# Spring Boot 1.5 Unable to display file upload error message on same page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I search a lot on internet try to find out a workable solution. But I did not got succeed, finally I am here for the solution.

I am trying to upload a file which is working fine, but the issue is file size or you can say request size. When request size is greater then allow in application.properties or default size then spring throws exception and it will redirect to error page.

I want that the error message should be display as validation message just like other validation in controller.

**Effort:**

```
    if (file.isEmpty() && (conf.getPhoto() == null || conf.getPhoto().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("fileUpload", "upload.file.required");
    } else if (!file.isEmpty() && !PNG_MIME_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(file.getContentType())) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("fileUpload", "upload.invalid.file.type");
    }

    else if (!file.isEmpty() && file.getSize() > IMG_SIZE_IN_BYTES) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("fileUpload", "upload.exceeded.file.size");
    }
```

As, above effort shows, i am checking size in controller and displaying size message, but this working only when the request size in less then the defined request size. When the request or size is greater then defined in application.properties file then the

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (10680249) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)

Exception is thrown and this will redirect the request to /error page. I want even exception thrown then the error message should be display on same page as a normal error.

Yes know I can increase the size in .properties file, but this is not the right solution.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any code to handle the exception thrown by Tomcat's file upload functionality. If you're not familiar with Exceptions & `try`/`catch` keywords, [you should read up on those](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

Comment: Well, I know i can create global exception handler as @ControllerAdvice or try/catch block which will work in if is thrown from controller. second one exception is thrown by spring filter and it is not reaching to my controller. third one i am looking to display message on same page not on to any exception page.